# Measurable functions could be injective but not bijective?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am trying to understand the concept of measurable functions. In several texts I found that if $(\Omega, \Sigma)$ is a measurable space, then $f: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is measurable if and only if one of the following conditions holds:

- $\{ x \in \Omega \colon f(x) < b\} \in \Sigma$ for every $b \in \mathbb{R}$
- $\{ x \in \Omega \colon f(x) > b\} \in \Sigma$ for every $b \in \mathbb{R}$
- $\{ x \in \Omega \colon f(x) \leq b\} \in \Sigma$ for every $b \in \mathbb{R}$
- $\{ x \in \Omega \colon f(x) \geq b\} \in \Sigma$ for every $b \in \mathbb{R}$

the texts say that note that $\{x \in \Omega : f(x) < b\} = f^{−1}((−∞, b))$

Now, my question is that if $f$ is not bijective, for instance, just injective, could exist values in $\mathbb{R}$ that not were generated by any value of $\Omega$, so it is not necessary that $f$ be bijective? why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\Omega=\{x_1,x_2\}$ be a two element set, and $f:\Omega\to\Bbb{R}$ be defined as $f(x_1):=1,f(x_2):=2$. This is clearly an injective, but not bijective function. Consider $\Sigma_1=\{\emptyset,\Omega\}$ the trivial $\sigma$-algebra, and $\Sigma_2=\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ the powerset. Then,

- $f$ is not $\Sigma_1$-$\mathcal{B}(\Bbb{R})$- measurable (for example, $f^{-1}(\{1\})=\{x_1\}\notin \Sigma_1$).
- $f$ is $\Sigma_2$-$\mathcal{B}(\Bbb{R})$-measurable, because if the domain has the power set as the $\sigma$-algebra, then every function is measurable.

So, it's possible to have injective, non-bijective, measurable functions, and it's also possible to have injective, non-bijective, non-measurable functions, and these are quite trivial examples.

---

For a slightly more non-trivial example, consider the real line with Borel $\sigma$-algebra. Let $\phi:\Bbb{R}\to(0,\infty)$ be a smooth injective function (for example $\phi(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}+\arctan(x)$ or $\phi(x)=e^x$). Then, $\phi$ is an example of an injective, non-bijective, Borel-measurable function (it's even smooth).

On the other hand, fix a non Borel-measurable set $E\subset \Bbb{R}$, and consider $f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ defined as
\begin{align}
f(x)&:=
\begin{cases}
\phi(x)&\text{if $x\in E$}\\
-\phi(x)&\text{else}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
Then, $f$ is injective, and not surjective ($f$ never takes the value $0$), and $f$ is not Borel-measurable, since $f^{-1}((0,\infty))=E$ was assumed to not be a Borel set.

So, bottom line is functions can be extremely crazily behaved.

Comment: Thank you peek, so it is not necessary that  all borel sets have the inverse in $\Sigma$? in your first example, $f^{-1}(\{  3\}) \notin \Sigma$

Comment: @carlos.rivera $f^{-1}(\{3\})=\emptyset\in \Sigma_1$. The empty set belongs to every $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: ahhh ok, I understand. :) thank you very much.