# How to prove a function as a measurable function?

Tags: linear-algebra, random-variables, measurable-functions

In continuation with [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4472129/measurable-functions-could-be-injective-but-not-bijective) .

Let $\Omega=\{x_1,x_2\}$ be a two element set, and $f:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ be defined as

$$f(x_1)=1,f(x_2)=2$$

Consider $\Sigma_1=\{\varnothing ,\Omega\}$ the trivial $\sigma$-algebra, and $\Sigma_2 = P(\Omega)$ the powerset. Then,
$f$ is $\Sigma_2$-$B(\mathbb R)$-measurable, because if the domain has the power set as the $\sigma$-algebra,then every function is measurable.
One of the comments in answer states $f^{−1}(\{3\})=\varnothing\in\Sigma_1$.The empty set belongs to every $\sigma$-algebra.

Does this also mean that $f(\{\phi\}) = \{3\}$?
Since a function should map every element from $\Omega$, is this function even defined for null set?

Comment: No. The only thing that $f^{-1}(\{3\})=\varnothing$ means is: there is no $\omega\in\Omega$ such that $f(\omega)=3$. In other wordings: the preimage of set $\{3\}\subseteq\mathbb R$ under function $f$ is empty.

Comment: The expressin $f(\{\varnothing\})$ makes no sense because $\{\varnothing\}$ is not an element of $\Omega$ and is neither a subset of $\Omega$. To make things complete: the expression $f(\varnothing)$ does make sense because $\varnothing\subseteq\Omega$. Then $f(\varnothing)$ denotes the image of this subset under $f$ and evidently this image is always empty: $f(\varnothing)=\varnothing$.